# Doctrine possible values for driver in DATABASE_URL

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine

In [Doctrine configuration reference (driver)](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/current/reference/configuration.html#driver) I see `pdo_mysql` as a possible value, but not `mysql`, which is the one defined by default in Symfony (in `DATABASE_URL`).

I have checked that it's using PDO even though `mysql` is defined as `driver` in `DATABASE_URL`, but I can't find any reference. Is it an alias of `pdo_mysql`?

On the other hand, in the [same reference page](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/current/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url) I see an example with `pdo-mysql`, not `pdo_mysql`. Is there any sort of transformation of `driver` within `DATABASE_URL`?

What are then all possible values for `driver` in `DATABASE_URL`?

Comment: Maybe find this useful.. Looks like it is [aliased here in the Doctrine DriverManager](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/4173dfc23de02e2ac0c99cfb16fcd8af5fedc23b/src/DriverManager.php#L99) (latest version).

Comment: @Bossman - Great, thank you! This should be documented